# Create Event on Teams Channel Calendar from Daemon application using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: calendar, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have a daemon application that needs to update calendars created in Teams channels.

As far as I can tell, these channel calendars (unlike traditional Outlook calendars) do not have easily accessible IDs, so the [Create event method for Calendars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)  is not possible.

The [Create event method for Group calendars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) documentation states that Application permissions are "not supported" so my daemon app cannot make changes.

Does a work around exist for this?  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

As per docs the current api does not support application permission so your app wont be able to change the calendar.